# Scope Variable with a Loop

Tags: python

I read a sentence in the official handbook of Python.

> If a lambda or def defined within a function is nested inside a loop, and the >nested function references an enclosing scope variable that is changed by that >loop, all functions generated within the loop will have the same value—the value >the referenced variable had in the last loop iteration. In such cases, you must >still use defaults to save the variable’s current value instead.

As for the script:

```
def makeActions():
     acts=[]
     for i in range(5):
         acts.append(lambda x: i**x)
     return acts
acts=makeActions()
print(acts)
```

I know how the problem looks like and how to solve it. But I just can not understand reason.
please have a look at my interpretations:

```
def makeActions():
    acts=[]
    for i in range(5):
        acts.append(lambda x: i**x) #step2-step6: each lambda would be stored 
                                    #in the list, however, with its own "i"
    return acts

acts=makeActions() #step1: when the function is called, the list would be 
                   #created. And lambda would be called as well.
print(acts)
```

**My point** is that in each iteration, each lambda would be called even if the parameter x is not given. Thus, in the list "acts", each element (namely each lambda) has different "i".

I know I am wrong, but could you tell me why? 
Thx!

Comment: What is printed and what did you expect?

Comment: actually, nothing but the memory address. I want to check the value of i, but nothing

Comment: "in each iteration, each lambda would be called...". Your code isn't actually calling the lambdas anywhere, just creating them. So I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Not clear why you're using lambda at all if you want values `return [i**2 for i in range(5)]`

Comment: @glibdud, by creating them, each lambda would be stored in the list?

Comment: Sure, but the lambda is just a callable, like a function. Creating it and calling it are two separate actions. You're doing the former, not the latter.

Comment: This [article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/) is very useful

Comment: @zwer, so can i say: before i call any lambda explicitly, their "i" are different in the list?

Comment: @cricket_007, i just read it and can't understand..

Comment: @wiesion, i read it before i posted the question. But Thanks all the same! :)

Comment: Just look at the example given in the documentation... Is that not what you're trying to do? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @cricket_007, i read the example and guessed the result. but it is not the same as i thought. And i couldn't understand..

Comment: It's a list comprehension, the documentation explains it fine. Again, I'm not sure I understand why you're trying to make lambdas here to square a number when you only need the result of that operation

Comment: @cricket_007 no, no. Don't worry! I get your points. Not a problem any more. Thanks!

Comment: @zwer. Thanks for the explanation. But i think the answer below explain this better. It would be really helpful, if you have a look at it.

Comment: @zwer - wiesion's answer is correct, I misunderstood your question - I thought you were receiving your values from the outside in which case they would be 'frozen' within the lambda context (as demonstrated in the answer, too).

Answer (score 4):

To clarify a bit more on the subject, the reference to `i` does not change within the lambda - you see that each iteration of `i` generates a new object:

```
def makeActions():
  acts=[]
  for i in range(5):
    print('i:', i, 'object id:', id(i))
    acts.append(lambda: id(i))
  print('final i:', i, 'object id:', id(i))
  return acts
acts=makeActions()
print([fn() for fn in acts])
```

Returns

```
i: 0 object id: 140418781832928
i: 1 object id: 140418781832960
i: 2 object id: 140418781832992
i: 3 object id: 140418781833024
i: 4 object id: 140418781833056
final i: 4 object id: 140418781833056
[140418781833056, 140418781833056, 140418781833056, 140418781833056, 140418781833056]
```

The reference from `i` always points to its last assigned object, thus the id of `i` will not change after its last alteration.

If you want to keep the value at the time of the lambda creation, you need to "trap" the value of the reference at the desired place and time, for instance you could delegate the lambda creation to a function:

```
def delegated(d):
  return lambda: id(d)

def makeDelegatedActions():
  acts=[]
  for i in range(5):
    print('i:', i, 'object id:', id(i))
    acts.append(delegated(i))
  print('final i:', i, 'object id:', id(i))
  return acts
acts=makeDelegatedActions()
print([fn() for fn in acts])
```

Which returns

```
i: 0 object id: 140418781832928
i: 1 object id: 140418781832960
i: 2 object id: 140418781832992
i: 3 object id: 140418781833024
i: 4 object id: 140418781833056
final i: 4 object id: 140418781833056
[140418781832928, 140418781832960, 140418781832992, 140418781833024, 140418781833056]
```

[Online demo here](https://repl.it/repls/CanineBlackCopyright)

Answer (score 2):

Each lambda will just know to fetch `i` from its enclosing scope, which is the `makeActions` call. They don't actually do so until they're called themselves. `i` is the same name within the same scope, it just happens to take different values during the loop, and will simply hold the last value after the loop finishes. So the lambdas just ended up creating 5 identical functions.

A variation that can work:

```
def expgen(n):
    def myexp(x):
        return n**x
    return myexp

acts = [expgen(i) for i in range(5)]
```

In this case, the scope that `n` is fetched from is that of `expgen`, which had distinct calls in the list comprehension, and each function will work independently.

Comment: Thx, but in each iteration, would lambda use the different i?

Comment: There's only one `i`. It resides in the `makeActions` call and is inherited by each of the `lambda`s. This is distinct from putting it in a default argument, which takes its value at that time and stores it among the defaults. The loop doesn't create a scope, let alone one per iteration; it just updates a variable and runs a chunk of code.